# Is there any way to run embedded jar file by using jni?

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface

My question is quite simple. I have an executable jar file which is embedded into c++ resource, now i want to load it and run it by using jni.

I know how to load from resource, i know how to run jar file saved on the disk by using jni.

I just want to run an embedded jar file which is loaded in to the memory. Also, need to be noted i dont want to save to the disk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964450/loading-a-jar-dynamically-from-memory https://gist.github.com/solomax/1783a36d678011c077100c2905a24a8c

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this by using C ++

Comment: it all applies to c++, you might have to write some java but you can call it from c++