# Minecraft Plugin and JSoup.jar

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm creating a Java Project in Eclipse, write some parser, which gives a random names with use a JSoup Library and when i started a server it gives me a error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup`. [Eclipse files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDpUQ.png).
I also use Json-simple and everything is fine with it. JSoup is added as an external JAR library, and the error occurs only when I use `Jsoup.connect().get;` that is, the imported org object.jsoup.nodes.Document does not cause errors.
P.s. I looked through my plugin using 7-zip and there is JSoup.jar in the libs folder, which means that the plugin is correctly assembled in a vmset with libraries.
[image]

Comment: Provide code, and error stacktrace

Comment: The error is here `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://randomus.ru/name?type=101&sex=0&count=100").get();`. Error stacktrace added in top.

Comment: Or you mean full code of function, where i call `Jsoup.connect()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your libraries in the server.

To fix it, you can:

1. Add them in the compiled jar. To do this, just check compilation options, or convert your project as [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or [gradle](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/)
2. Use another plugin that implement them.
3. Load library jar from your plugin such as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-to-load-jar-files-dynamically-at-runtime) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204913/how-to-add-an-external-jar-file-to-the-classpath-dynamically-at-runtime)